# How do I print out a break instruction in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, exception, mips, break

I'm new to MIPS programming, and I'm working on a program to become more familiar with exception handling.

When an exception occurs, I print out the address of where the exception occurred, followed by the exception occurred. After these messages print, the program hits a break statement:

```
break 100
```

And then terminates the program.

My question is, is there a way I can print out this instruction when it gets hit?
What I want to print out would be something like:

*exception address* Cause: *exception type* break 100

Comment: What do you mean 'the register where it occured'? For example `div $t0 $t1 $t2` causes a divide by zero exception, which one is the 'register where the exception occured'?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach I'm sorry, that was a mistake on my part, what I'm actually doing is is getting the exception type from coprocessor 0

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You have already figured out how to print the exception address and exception type and now you want to know how to print the break code?

Answer (score 1):

Register $14 in coprocessor 0 holds the break code.
Load that instruction into memory, then load that word. You need to shift past the first 6 bits to get the break code.

```
mfc0 $a0, $14   
lw $a0, ($a0)
srl $a0, $a0, 6 
li $v0, 1   
syscall
```

Comment: How might I load the instruction word and extract the number?

Comment: @otis92 Line 2 will load the word, line 3 will extract the number. Save the number in $a0 so you can print it out with the "1 syscall"